# QT compilation, can't find includes

Tags: c++, qt, include

I am trying to compile QT code, but for some reason the compiler complains that it can't find the include files even when I have specified their paths in my makefile

**asd.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

}
```

**Compilation command**

```
g++ -I. -I/home/marti/Qt/6.2.2/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/home/marti/Qt/6.2.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/marti/Qt/6.2.2/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -c asd.cpp -o out/asd.o
```

**Error**

```
asd.cpp:1:10: fatal error: QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As you can see I have specified the path to `QtWidgets`..I have no idea why it's unable to find `QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h`

Comment: Try instead `#include <qtwidgetsglobal.h>`

Comment: If you're trying to `#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>` then the compiler option should probably be `-I/home/marti/Qt/6.2.2/gcc_64/include`.  Note, however, that `qtwidgetsglobal.h` is not a documented header.  Instead you should specify the real headers required.

Comment: @G.M. Oh yes.. I really should change to `-I/home/marti/Qt/6.2.2/gcc_64/include` and that works. Thanks!

Comment: Or use a proper build system like e.g. qmake or cmake which adds those includes and libraries in a much more sane way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not include the header files directly. You instead include "aliases". In your case you probably just want to:

```
# include <QWidget>
```

See also the [documentation for QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qwidget.html) that explicitly states that on the very top of the page.